# Create multilingual website with JavaScript and Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-applications, multilingual

I'm creating a web-application and I want to make it possible for the user to choose between 2 or 3 languages.

What is the best way of doing this, using HTML, JavaScript and Node.js?

Is there a difference in performance when using a client-side or server side solution for this? (Having mobile users in mind)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a client-side/front-end solution then you could use https://github.com/coolbloke1324/jquery-lang-js

Comment: Do you know any server side solutions?

Comment: No. I don't have experience with Node but I know its server side JS. Maybe you can run jQuery plugins server-side? Not sure if its possible...